# Network error when exporting from localhost in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am managing a database on AWS but I am doing that with the latest Docker image (of phpMyAdmin) running on the localhost. Most things work well but I get the message "Network error" when I try to export tables from the database. The URL is `http://localhost:8080/index.php?route=/export`

How do I debug this?

[image: Network error]

Comment: Why manage your database from a Docker image rather than using RDS?

Comment: Because PMA lets me run queries and browse the data in an easy way. I don't think there is a nice GUI in the AWS web console but I might be wrong.

Comment: You can still use PhpMyAdmin and connect it to RDS: https://www.serverkaka.com/2018/09/connect-aws-rds-mysql-instance-with-phpmyadmin.html

Comment: Thank you, isn't that what I do (more or less) but with a docker container on localhost?

Comment: With RDS, the connection to it will actually work.

Comment: I am using RDS in AWS, it is just the PMA instance that is running locally.

Comment: Then why are you using `localhost`?  You should be using the RDS host name to connect to the database, and the host name of your docker image to connect to PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: I have a RDS hostname to the database server (I added that to the PMA configuration), th DB server does not run a PHP instance. Just to be clear most things work with this setup but not export.